# How do I remove spammy links in WP theme footer?

Tags: php

I got a little obstruction. I have a free theme, which I like, but I found out that in the footer there are too many commercial links (Let me say spammy links). I want to keep the credits to the author. But I need to remove the ''spam'' links. I've tried many things for few hour by now, but I am not familiar with PHP so I stuck. Here is my code in functions.php

```
function wp_initialize_the_theme_load() { 
    if (!function_exists("wp_initialize_the_theme")) { 
        wp_initialize_the_theme_message(); die; 
        } 
    } 

    function wp_initialize_the_theme_finish() { 
    $uri = strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
    if(is_admin() || substr_count($uri, "wp-admin") > 0 || substr_count($uri, "wp-login") > 0 ) { 
    /* */ } 
        else { 
        $l = ' | Theme Designed by: <?php echo wp_theme_credits(0); ?>  | Thanks to <?php echo wp_theme_credits(1); ?>, <?php echo wp_theme_credits(2); ?> and <?php echo wp_theme_credits(3); ?>'; 
        $f = dirname(__file__) . "/footer.php"; 
        $fd = fopen($f, "r"); 
        $c = fread($fd, filesize($f)); 
        $lp = preg_quote($l, "/"); 
        fclose($fd); 
        if ( strpos($c, $l) == 0 ) { 
            wp_initialize_the_theme_message(); die; 
            } 
        } 
} 

wp_initialize_the_theme_finish(); 

function wp_theme_credits($no){
    if(is_numeric($no)){
        global $wp_theme_globals,$theme;$the_wp_theme_globals=unserialize(base64_decode($wp_theme_globals));
        $page=md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $initilize_set=get_option('wp_theme_initilize_set_'.str_replace(' ','_',strtolower(trim($theme->theme_name))));
        if(!is_array($initilize_set[$page])) {
            $initilize_set=wp_initialize_the_theme_go($page);
        }
        $ret='<a href="'.$the_wp_theme_globals[$no][$initilize_set[$page][$no]].'">'.$initilize_set[$page][$no].'</a>';
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$l = ' | Theme Designed by: <?php echo wp_theme_credits(0); ?>  | Thanks to <?php echo wp_theme_credits(1); ?>, <?php echo wp_theme_credits(2); ?> and <?php echo wp_theme_credits(3); ?>';
```

With:

```
$l = ' | Theme Designed by: <?php echo wp_theme_credits(0); ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php comment out the line

```
wp_initialize_the_theme_finish();
```

to

```
//  wp_initialize_the_theme_finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a child theme, copy your free theme's footer.php over to your child theme, and make your edits there. Any changes you make to your theme files will be overridden when your theme upgrades. Editing PHP and HTML in footer.php is probably easier for you than creating functions to delete or replace that code.